# Prove that the form $f(x^2+y^2)x\,dx +f(x^2+y^2)y\,dy $ is closed for a continuous $f$.

Tags: calculus, integration, differential-forms

Prove that the form $f(x^2+y^2)x\,dx +f(x^2+y^2)y\,dy $ is closed for a continuous $f$. I'm not even sure if the exterior derivative exists in this case, but I need to prove that the integral of the form over any closed path is equal to $0$.

I tried using a pullback to polar coordinates $\phi(r,\theta) = (r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$ and got that the integral over a closed path is:

$$\int f(r^2)rd \text{ ??}$$

This is after simplification. I still don't understand formally how the pullback should look, and I think I did it wrong. I don't know what's supposed to go after the $d$, hence the ??.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** As Tsemo Aristide pointed, we prove below that the vector field is conservative. If by closed you mean a closed differential form, it is easy to come with examples of continuous functions $f$ for which $f(x^2+y^2)x$ is not differentiable with respect to $x$, and any such example would be a counterexample to the problem. Indeed

$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x^2+y_0^2)x - f(a^2+y_0^2)a}{x-a}=\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x^2+y_0^2)x - f(x^2+y_0^2)a}{x-a}+\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x^2+y_0^2)a - f(a^2+y_0^2)a}{x-a}$$

As the first limit exists by the continuity of $f$, all you need is to make sure $a \neq 0$ and that $f(x^2+\alpha)$ is not differentiable at $a$ for a fixed $\alpha$.

**Hint** Let $F$ be an antiderivative of $f$, and define the vector field

$$G(x,y) =\frac{1}{2}F(x^2+y^2)$$

What is the gradient of $G$?

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So $dx$ and $dy$ just transform to $dr d\theta$?

Comment: @JohnB There is no need to switch to polar coordinates ;)

Comment: Why you can differentiate $G$ twice here?

Comment: I don't see how to formally justify this without switching to polar coordinates..

Comment: @TsemoAristide You don't need to, you only need to differentiate once and make sure that the derivatives are continuous.... There is a theorem which says that if $G$ is a function with continuous gradient then $$\int_C \nabla G d r = G(b)-G(a)$$ where $C$ is any curve between $a$ and $b$... If the curve is closed.....

Comment: Alright, thanks!

Comment: @JohnB  The integral of $\nabla f$ is always path independent.

Comment: A form is closed is its differential is zero, the differential of $G$ is the form $h$ you want to show that $dh=0$, if $f$ is not differentiable, how are you sure you can compute $dh$?